# I cant use a single number on my function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have this function here that calls another function. The problem is that I cant use single numbers in input prompt like (1, 2, 3) I have to add a letter like (a1, a2, a3) for this to work.

Actually the function "PrintSelectetoPDF" works fine when Im not using a user input prompt and just using the loop in my database. The problem is that Im getting an error "too many requests" after 5 or 6 pdfs so this is a "solution" but I really need to use single numbers in my sheet.

Im trying this

```
function promptUserToSelectInvoices(data) {
  // Prompts the user to enter invoice numbers separated by commas
  var selectedInvoices = [];
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Select Invoices to Print', 'Enter the invoice numbers separated by commas:', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  
  if (response.getSelectedButton() === ui.Button.OK) {
    var input = response.getResponseText().trim();
    selectedInvoices = input.split(',').map(function(value) {
      return value.trim();
    });

    // Calls the PrintSelectedToPDF() function with the selectedInvoices array
    PrintSelectedToPDF(selectedInvoices);
  }
}

function PrintSelectedToPDF(invoicesToPrint) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var databaseSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Database');
  var invoiceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Invoice');
  
  var dataRange = databaseSheet.getRange(2, 1, databaseSheet.getLastRow() -1, 1);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var valueToPrint = data[i][0];
    
    // Check if invoicesToPrint is empty or includes the current invoice number
    if (invoicesToPrint.length === 0 || invoicesToPrint.includes(valueToPrint)) {
      invoiceSheet.getRange('F12').setValue(valueToPrint);
      
      var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheet.getId() + '/export?';
      var params = {
        exportFormat: 'pdf',
        format: 'pdf',
        size: 'letter',
        portrait: 'true',
        fitw: 'true',
        sheetnames: 'false',
        printtitle: 'false',
        top_margin: 0,
        bottom_margin: 0,
        left_margin: 0,
        right_margin: 0,
        gid: invoiceSheet.getSheetId()
      };
      
      var range = invoiceSheet.getDataRange();
      var rangeParam = '&range=' + range.getA1Notation();
      url += getUrlParams(params) + rangeParam;
      
      var backoffTime = 500;
      var maxBackoffTime = 5000;
      var attempts = 0;
      var response;
      
      while (true) {
        try {
          Utilities.sleep(backoffTime);
          response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
            headers: {
              Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
            },
            muteHttpExceptions: true
          });
          
          break; // Break out of the while loop if the request is successful
        } catch (e) {
          if (e.message.indexOf('Exception: Request failed for') === -1 || e.message.indexOf('returned code 429') === -1) {
            throw e; // Throw an exception if it's not a 429 error
          }
          
          attempts++;
          if (attempts >= 5) {
            throw e; // If the maximum number of attempts is reached, throw an exception
          }
          
          backoffTime *= 2; // Exponential backoff
          backoffTime = Math.min(backoffTime, maxBackoffTime); // Limit backoff time to maximum value
        }
      }
      
      var fileName = 'Invoice_' + valueToPrint + '.pdf';
      var downloadsFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFoldersByName('Reportes_2B').next();
      var file = downloadsFolder.createFile(response.getBlob().setName(fileName));
      var fileUrl = file.getUrl();
      Logger.log('PDF file URL: ' + fileUrl);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Changed tag from Java to Javascript because this question doesn't contain any Java code.

Comment: `promptUserToSelectInvoices` has a parameter but it's not used anywhere

Comment: But I think thats not the problem because how I said my function works well when using numbers and letters :(

Comment: What happens if you do use single numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the root issue happens when creating the 'selectedInvoices' variable, that map creates an array of strings and the values you retrieve later on from your database sheet are integers. Please try this code:

```
function promptUserToSelectInvoices(data) {
  // Prompts the user to enter invoice numbers separated by commas
  var selectedInvoices = [];
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Select Invoices to Print', 'Enter the invoice numbers separated by commas:', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  if (response.getSelectedButton() === ui.Button.OK) {
    var input = response.getResponseText().trim();
    selectedInvoices = input.split(',').map(function(value) {
    return parseInt(value.trim()); //This is the updated line
  });
 
  // Calls the PrintSelectedToPDF() function with the selectedInvoices array
  PrintSelectedToPDF(selectedInvoices);

 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the problem :)